# How o force the user to select a single checkbox with HTML?

Tags: html, checkbox

I am creating a quiz in HTML. The questionnaire can be answered by selecting a checkbox. So far try this:

```
<h3>This is question 1?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" id="c01" value="0"/> answer A
<input type="radio" name="answer2" id="c02" value="0" /> answer B
<h3>This is question 2?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" id="c03" value="0"/> answer 1
<input type="radio" name="answer4" id="c04" value="0" /> answer 2
<input type="radio" name="answer5" id="c05" value="0"/> answer 3
```

However, the previous statement doesnt work because I only want to be possible to select one and only one answer (selecting more than one checkbox per answer is not allowed). How can I force the user to only select a single checkbox for each different question by only using html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fieldset:

```html
<fieldset id="question1">
<legend>Question 1:</legend>
    <input type="radio" value="value1" name="question1">Answer 1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="value2" name="question1">Answer 2</input>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="question2">
<legend>Question 2:</legend>
    <input type="radio" value="value1" name="question2">Answer 1</input>
    <input type="radio" value="value2" name="question2">Answer 2</input>
</fieldset>
```

Without fieldset:

```html
<h3>This is question 1?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="value1" name="question1">Answer 1</input>
<input type="radio" value="value2" name="question1">Answer 2</input>

<h3>This is question 2?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="value1" name="question2">Answer 1</input>
<input type="radio" value="value2" name="question2">Answer 2</input>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got confused with the names

Answer (score 0):

You need to give all the input type="radio" the same name, this will turn them into radio buttons rather than checkboxes like they are essentially now.

Thanks,